# set vs list performance difference

Tags: python, performance

I was solving [this](https://projecteuler.net/problem=29) question from project Euler, in python 3.9. One thing caught my attention was using a set performs better than using a list.

[image]

Chart above shows time vs number of items for set and list. List time increase exponentially, while sets perform on relatively constant performance.

My question is why list has poor performance when number of items increase, while sets perform on quite constant performance?

Here is my code:

```
from time import perf_counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def using_set(limit):
    seq = set()
    for i in range(2,limit):
        for j in range(2,limit):
            seq.add(i**j)
    #print(len(seq))

def using_list(limit):
    l = []
    for a in range(2,limit):
        for b in range (2,limit):
            c = a**b
            if c not in l:
                l.append(c)
    #print(len(l))

yset = []
ylist = []
xline = []
for i in range(1, 10_00, 10):
    start = perf_counter()
    using_set(i)
    end = perf_counter()
    yset.append(end - start)
    xline.append(i)

    start = perf_counter()
    using_list(i)
    end = perf_counter()
    ylist.append(end-start)
plt.plot(xline, yset, label="set")
plt.plot(xline, ylist, label="list")
plt.xlabel("number of items")
plt.ylabel("time (seconds)")
plt.title("Set vs List time performance")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: this is in terms of accessing ? or insertiion?

Comment: It depends on which operation you perform with a set or a list. Some operations are more efficient for sets, some are more efficient for lists.

Comment: Also it seems that there are more differences between `using_set` and `using_list` than just replacing a set with a list. e.g. `using_list` doesn't use `limit` at all. This makes the orange line a horizontal obviously.

Comment: I don't know for certain so I'll make a guess. When you append to a list, all that's happening (conceptually) is that your datum gets glued to the end of the existing list with no checks other than to make sure that the list can grow to accommodate it. However, sets have a crucial aspect of non-duplication and therefore when you attempt to add any datum to a set there has to be a check to ensure that no duplication occurs. As I said, just a guess

Comment: @mkrieger1, facepalming myself right now. Let me check that again.

Comment: Corrected the code and the chart. I got what I expected now, but still wondering why there is a performance difference between two.

Comment: When you check `if c not in l:` that's gonna take longer and longer the more items there are in the list whereas I don't think sets have that problem

Comment: @RolvApneseth, why do you think sets don't have that problem?

Comment: Sets store things with a hash table so lookup time is O(1) unlike lists which are O(N)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference for this would be the [Python wiki "Time Complexity" page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

In particular, adding an item to a set has complexity O(1) on average, meaning constant time regardless of the size of the set; meawhile, list `x in l` has complexity O(n), meaning it grows linearly with the size of the list.